# Download a file using a ASP.NET Core Console Application From API Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an API which generates Word documents and serves them up on request when an endpoint is used, eg https://myapi.com/GetDocumentById/{id}

I'm trying to get my console application to access the URL and save the file to the local drive, eg C:\Temp

All solutions I've come accross so far have been centred around MVC which I'm obviously not using.

Could someone point me in the right direction please? What should I be using? I can't use WebClient as `DownloadFile` expects a filename and I won't necessarily know it. I need to download the generated file from the endpoint.

Thanks

Comment: Try `HttpClient`. I assume it's as simple as a `GET` method to the correct url. When you get a succesfull statuscode you are halfway there. Then just read the file from the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` to receive the file which returns from api, I have created a simple demo for your reference.

First, to create word file, you need to download `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` dll in your api project.

Api:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GetDocumentByIdController : ControllerBase
    {
       [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GenerateDocx(int id)
        {
            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                {
                    // Add a main document part. 
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    // Create the document structure and add some text.
                    mainPart.Document = new Document();
                    Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                    Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                    Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                     run.AppendChild(new Text("The text in docx which created by " + id.ToString()));
                }
                return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            }
        }
    }
```

Console app:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:50855/api/ApiCode/GenerateDocx/1");
                builder.Query = "id=1";// you can pass any other value
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var contentBytes = client.GetByteArrayAsync(builder.Uri).Result;
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(contentBytes);
                FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\ABC.docx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                stream.WriteTo(file);
                file.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw; //throws 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'
            }
        }
    }
```

After running the console app, you will find `a word file named ABC` in the path of C:\Temp.

Answer (score 1):

```html
public async Task<string> DownloadFile(string guid)
{
  
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo($"{guid}.txt");
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_url}/api/files?guid={guid}");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    await using var ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    await using var fs = File.Create(fileInfo.FullName);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ms.CopyTo(fs);     
    return fileInfo.FullName;
}
```